# Android - use Logan Square library to parse a JSON string

Tags: android, json, parsing

I stumbled upon this library while looking for a fast JSON parser in Android: https://github.com/bluelinelabs/LoganSquare

However it was last updated 8 years ago and the gradle mentioned on the page doesn't work.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

dependencies {
    apt 'com.bluelinelabs:logansquare-compiler:1.3.6'
    compile 'com.bluelinelabs:logansquare:1.3.6'
}
```

Does anyone have any success with it? Or is it dead?

Comment: Please post the error you get. Is it `Could not get unknown property 'compile'`?